# I was iterating over a List and print each element, why the code throws error?

Tags: python

I was iterating over a List and print each element, the code is very simply, but the program throws error.

[image]

Comment: don't post screenshots, copy and paste code and error instead please.

Comment: I assume you redefined the `print` keyword as an integer in your code before...

Comment: @Julien Never define *print* keyword anywhere else, anyway restarting Jupyter kernel solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redefined `print` somewhere else in your code.  You can test this by simply running:

```
print
```

It will likely give you an integer.  Try resetting your kernel.

Comment: It's weird that I didn't define **print** anywhere, nevertheless, restarting kernel works, thanks.